# Uploading files with Synapse

Tags: delphi, upload, ararat-synapse

I need to upload a file to the site rghost.net:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HTTP: THTTPSendEx;
  Data: TMultipartFormDataStream;
  sHTML: string; //Received HTML code from web
  upload_url, fireld_name: string;
begin
  upload_url:='http://kaon.rghost.ru/files';
  fireld_name:='file';
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    HTTP:=THTTPSEndEx.Create;
    HTTP.UserAgent:='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; I; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) '+
                    'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0';
    Data:=TMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      //Data.AddFile(fireld_name, OpenDialog1.FileName);
      Data.AddFile(fireld_name, OpenDialog1.Filename);
      Data.DataEnd;
      if HTTP.Post(upload_url,Data,sHTML) then
      begin
      end;
    finally
      FreeAndNil(HTTP);
      FreeAndNil(Data);
    end;
    Memo1.Text := sHTML;
    ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'page.html', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  end;
end;
```

The program should return a reference to a file, but it returns:

> 500 - your request could not be processed at the moment, because of an error on the server.

What is wrong?

Comment: I'd try to debug this with a known good download source. If you have your own webserver (or website) you can see the request coming (in the log files). Right now you're dealing with 2 unknowns (the operations of your code + the operation on the other side).

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong is exactly what the message says: **an error on the server.**

This can mean one of two things.  Either the problem's not in your code and there's nothing you can do about it, or the problem *is* in your code and the website is returning the wrong error message.  Either way, you need to contact the folks behind rghost to get any idea of what's really going on.  500-level errors are things that have to be dealt with on their end, not yours.

Comment: The problem in the code, as I tested it on mine production server. And it did not work (error 302)